# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on custom filter

Tags: java, hibernate, servlet-filters

I have a java web project, I'm using Hibernate, JSF and Primefaces. 
I have a problem with Hibernate.

I got this exception:

```
Exception starting filter conexaoFiter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crud.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter
```

I set Hibernate in the `Web.xml` like this:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>conexaoFiter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.crud.filter.ConexaoHibernateFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>conexaoFiter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The Hibernate filter class:

```
package com.crud.filter;
public class ConexaoHibernateFilter implements Filter {

 private SessionFactory sf;

 public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
}

 public void destroy() {
}

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException {

    try {

        this.sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

        chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

        this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        this.sf.getCurrentSession().close();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        try {
            if (this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                this.sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
}

}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: is this by chance <filter-name>conexaoFiter</filter-name> or a mistake as this should be <filter-name>conexaoFilter</filter-name>

Comment: Is that really the root cause of the exception? Well, then the filter class is obviously missing in the webapp's runtime classpath.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't see my spelling mistake.